# Doctrine 2.2 proxies classname

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I upgraded my doctrine version from 2.0 to 2.2.
I didn't change my doctrine config but when i generated proxies, proxy classnames and namspaces  changed.
The files classnames has been changed From 'ModelsUserProxy.php' to '__CG__ModelsUser.php' , my proxies namespaces from 'Models\Proxies'  to '\Models\Proxies__CG__\Models' and my classnames from 'ModelsUserProxy' to 'User'.

I saw many questions concerning this but no clear explain for me.
What have changed exactly in the new version concerning proxy management ?

I am using Doctrine autoloader for whole my project and here is my doctrine config.

```
    $configDoctrine = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
    $configDoctrine->setMetadataCacheImpl(new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache());

    // Fichiers contenant les informations du schéma de la base de données
    $driver = $configDoctrine->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(APPLICATION_PATH.'/Models/');
    $configDoctrine->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);

    $configDoctrine->setQueryCacheImpl(new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache());
    $configDoctrine->setProxyDir(APPLICATION_PATH.'/Models/Proxies');
    $configDoctrine->setProxyNamespace('\Models\Proxies');
    $configDoctrine->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(false);
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you tries to do? I didn't understand the question...

Comment: Doctrine proxies are internal classes and should not be handled directly.  So it really does not matter what they are called.  If you code relies on proxy names then refactor your code.  However, I believe the new naming was mostly to deal with caching entities with the same name from different namespaces.